# Angular Google Maps not refreshing after type change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, maps, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to change dynamically the type of the map, but it doesn't refresh. 
This is how I created the map in html file with the change type button

```
<button ng-click="trackCtrl.changeMap()">Change</button>
<ui-gmap-google-map refresh="trackCtrl.refreshType"
  center='trackCtrl.map.center' zoom='trackCtrl.map.zoom'>

  <ui-gmap-map-type options="trackCtrl.mapType" refresh="$ctrl.refreshMap">
  </ui-gmap-map-type>

</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

JS file:

```
$ctrl.map = {
  center: {
    latitude: $ctrl.track.path[0].latitude,
    longitude: $ctrl.track.path[0].longitude
  },
  zoom: 5
};
$ctrl.refreshMap = false;
```

Then, when I click de button:

```
$ctrl.changeMap = function() {
    $ctrl.mapType = mapService.getOSM();
    $ctrl.refreshMap = true;
  }
```

However, if I change the map type outside the function, and it get executed with the controller, it works fine. So I think the problem is that it isnt being refreshed.

Thanks in advance